# How can I create a 3 dot pop-up menu in the Flutter app bar similar to iOS with using a Cupertino package for iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-cupertino

How to make a 3 dot pop-up menu in the app bar in Flutter like ios. I do not want to use a material package cause developing for ios. Image link below

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwPhU.png)

I have already tried multiple things like 1. CupertinoContextMenu (CupertinoContextMenuAction) only work on long press(tap) and I don't want that. I want it with a single tap on the user. 2. Wrapped it inside a gesture detector but it does not work. 3. Used modal sheet but I don't want it like that. I want just a popup menu

Please tell me if there are any methods to Trigger CupertinoContextMenuAction with a single tap or any different methods that will also help

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to take the code of `_ContextMenuRoute` and adapt it to your needs.

Or use [pull_down_button](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_down_button) package

[image]

Comment: The pull_down_menu package is such a pristine job! Definitely a great option to consider.